# Conexion de 2 base de datos en un mismo projecto con node Js

Tags: sql-server, nodejs, mongodb

Hola muy buenas días o noches, quisiera preguntar si es posible conectar 2 base de datos, tanto una PostgreSQL y otra es MongoDb en un mismo archivo de index.js de un proyecto de NodeJS? y ademas usar la misma ruta de la api tanto para mongodb, como postgreSQL
En el código se muestra como esta escrito el archivo de index.js

Muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda o comentario, todo ayuda a seguir creciendo como programador novato

```
//Archivo principal de index.js

import express from 'express'; //framework de javascript
//const express=require('express');
import morgan from 'morgan'; //modulo que permite ver por terminal las peticiones al servidor
//const morgan=require('morgan');
import cors from 'cors'; //modulo permite cruce de informacion entre servidor y cliente
//const cors=require('cors');

import path from 'path'; //modulo que permite el direccionamiento de las carpetas del sistema
import mongoose from 'mongoose'; //modulo ODM, para el paso de la base de datos mongodb
import router from './routes'; //modulo de rutas del sistema
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Conexión a la base de datos MongoDB
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const dbUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/po2';
mongoose.connect(dbUrl, {
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true
    })
    .then(mongoose => console.log('Conectado a la BD en el puerto 27017'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
//_-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


//inicializacion
const app = express();
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//MIDDLEWARE del SISTEMA
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

//RUTAS del SISTEMA SOLO ES USADA CON MONGODB
app.use('/api', router);


//Asignacion de puerto a la aplicacion
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
//app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3003);

//Puesta en marcha de la aplicacion

//-----------------------------------------------------
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('server on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Si que es posible, pero tu pregunta es muy amplia. ¿Podrías mostrar algo de lo que hayas intentado y exactamente lo que te causa problemas? Saludos

Comment: Ahí fue editada la pregunta y se agregaron mas detalles de lo que se busca hacer, muchas gracias

Comment: y la ruta, como sabe de que base de datos debe leer?

Comment: Ok, tienes una conexión a MongoDB, ¿dónde o cómo vas a conectar a otro motor de DB diferente? ¿Qué consultas realizarás a una y otra? Aún falta info de lo que pretendes hacer. Saludos